# data is getting stored but i cannot get a json as response

Tags: mern

```
const register = async(req, res) => {
    try {
   
        const {username, email, phone, password} = req.body;

        const userExists = await User.findOne({email: email});

        if (userExists) {
            return res.status(400).json({msg:"email already exists"});
        }
        const usercreated = await User.create({username, email, phone, password});
        res.status(200).json({msg: usercreated});

    }
    catch(error) {
        res.status(500).json({msg: "internal server error"});
    }
};
```

data is getting stored in database, i.e. user.create is working but i cannot get the required json as response

Answer (score 0):

I think, this issue might be due to the security reasons. Here the object includes the password which should not be sent to the client. Also, Mongoose might be adding some properties to the user object that cannot be converted to JSON.

Try sending back the properties you need (username, email, phone):

```
const register = async(req, res) => {
try {

    const {username, email, phone, password} = req.body;

    const userExists = await User.findOne({email: email});

    if (userExists) {
        return res.status(400).json({msg:"email already exists"});
    }
    const usercreated = await User.create({username, email, phone, password});
    res.status(200).json({msg: "User created successfully", user: {username: usercreated.username, email: usercreated.email, phone: usercreated.phone}});

}
catch(error) {
    res.status(500).json({msg: "internal server error"});
}
};
```